# How to Re-load ReactJS Component in Vanilla HTML / JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs, dom

This may be a stupid question. But essentially, I am creating a React Modal component that can be used in any vanilla HTML / JS files. I am able to create a bundle.js file out of my React component using Webpack, which can then be injected into the div tag of a Vanilla HTML file as such:

```
<div id="my-modal-target"></div>
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

Since I'm trying to create a modal, what's happening is that whenever the user clicks "exit", my React component would conditionally render the modal to be hidden. However, I am trying to figure out how to re-load the React component by clicking a button in the target Vanilla HTML file. I would appreciate any suggestions on how I should proceed. Here is some stuff I have tried:

- using "ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById(DIV_TAG_NAME));" to forcefully unmount the React component from the div tag in the target HTML, and then re-loading the div tag using JQuery. However, this seems to cause a CORS issue that will not let me re-load the div tag. Furthermore, this just doesn't seem like a good practice on the React side.
- on button click in the Vanilla HTML file, it passes in a prop into the React component. However, this doesn't seem to work, as props are only passed in when the React component is first loaded. In other words, if change the props in the Vanilla HTML file, it will not affect the React component.

Thank you so much in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways by which you can accomplish React/non-React communication.

## Using custom events

While every methods have pros and cons, this one as the advantage of being framework-agnostic. You could do the same for a Vue component and vanilla js as well. The downside is that you need to find a way to manage and document events in a clean fashion or else your app can quickly become unmaintainable.

---

Inside your component, you need to create and listen for a custom event. Then, you can dispatch it from anywhere and the component will catch it and update accordingly.

```js
const OPEN_EVENT_NAME = 'open';
const CLOSE_EVENT_NAME = 'close';

const container = document.querySelector('#app');

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
 
    this.state = {
      open: true,
    }
    
    // Bind the "open" and "close" events to their respective functions
    container.addEventListener(OPEN_EVENT_NAME, this.openModal);
    container.addEventListener(CLOSE_EVENT_NAME, this.closeModal);
  }
  
  openModal = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true });
  }
  
  closeModal = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>The modal is {this.state.open ? 'open' : 'closed'}</div>
    )
  };
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, container);

// Create custom events
const openEvent = new Event(OPEN_EVENT_NAME);
const closeEvent = new Event(CLOSE_EVENT_NAME);

// Create events dispatchers
const openModal = () => container.dispatchEvent(openEvent);
const closeModal = () => container.dispatchEvent(closeEvent);

// Dispatch events on buttons click
document.querySelector('#open-btn').addEventListener('click', openModal);
document.querySelector('#close-btn').addEventListener('click', closeModal);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'system-ui';
  padding: 12px;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

hr {
  margin: 12px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<h2>
This is React
</h2>
<div id="app"></div>

<hr>

<h2>
This is not React
</h2>

<button id="open-btn">
Open modal
</button>

<button id="close-btn">
Close modal
</button>
```

## Using refs

Refs are generally used to access the underlying DOM element of a React component.

They can also be used to attach a component to the window object, thereby accessing its state and exposing its methods.

This method is less error prone because you talk the same language as your component (state, methods, etc.) but this is also a downside because this implies that the end user of your component has some familiarity with React, this which may not be the case.

---

This is how to do it, [thanks to this article](https://brettdewoody.com/accessing-component-methods-and-state-from-outside-react/).

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
 
    this.state = {
      open: true,
    }
  }
  
  openModal = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true });
  }
  
  closeModal = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>The modal is {this.state.open ? 'open' : 'closed'}</div>
    )
  };
}

ReactDOM.render(<App ref={myComponent => window.myComponent = myComponent} />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'system-ui';
  padding: 12px;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

hr {
  margin: 12px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<h2>
This is React
</h2>
<div id="app"></div>

<hr>

<h2>
This is not React
</h2>

<button onclick="window.myComponent.openModal()">
Open modal
</button>

<button onclick="window.myComponent.closeModal()">
Close modal
</button>
```

## -- Update --

As you're using React hooks and you can't reference a functional component, I wouldn't suggest using approach number 2.

I built a mini example of how I would implement approach number 1 (using events to communicate with React).

Like stated above, this provides a much nicer API to end users and may be the cleanest solution of the two.

[This demo is available here.](https://jsfiddle.net/6gp52y97/)

Comment: Hi, Julien. I tried out the "ref" example. Do you have any idea how that I can use this for React Hooks?  Right now, I have the error "functional components cannot be given refs".

Comment: I don't think this is applicable in this case because, as you have seen, you can't use refs with a functional component as you would with a class component.
If I were to design such a library that uses React as the view layer, I would add a wrapper javascript class that would act as a nicer API to interact with the component. I updated my answer with an example of such an implementation.